# Ubuntu 12.04 : No video, image thumbnails after repairing partitions

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

I recently ran into some problem that required I use Boot Repair to repair partitions. That worked fine but I cannot view any thumbnails anymore, all video and image files just show standard icons.

Some help would be appreciated as I haven't been having any luck with this problem.

Comment: Maybe you should install and run `dconf-editor` and have a look at the values of the following keys : 1) `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-image-thumbnails` 2) `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences thumbnail-limit` 3) `org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try reinstalling gnome keep in mind though that if you have uninstalled unity this may be difficult so an understanding of ALT+FX would be useful

sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell